# How to convert two lists into adjacency matrix SQL Server T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table in SQL Server 2005 that contains two columns Fruit and Colour as shown below

```
Fruit          Colour
Apple          Red
Orange         Red
Berry          Green
PineApple      Green
```

Now i want to convert it into an adjacency matrix query
as shown below

```
                Red        Green
Apple           1          0
Orange          1          0
Berry           0          1
PineApple       0          1
```

what i want to do is give 1 if Fruit and Colour are there 
else i want to give a 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was hard to avoid those null values in the pivot.

```
declare @t table (fruit varchar(10), colour varchar(10))

insert @t
select 'Apple',     'Red'   union all
select 'Orange',    'Red'   union all
select 'Berry',     'Green' union all
select 'PineApple', 'Green'

select * from (
select a.fruit, b.colour, case when c.fruit is null then 0 else 1 end found from 
(select distinct fruit, colour from @t) a
cross join 
(select distinct colour from @t) b
left outer join 
(select distinct fruit, colour from @t) c
on a.fruit = c.fruit and b.colour = c.colour) d
PIVOT
(max(found)  
FOR colour
in([red],[green])  
)AS p
order by 3, 1
```

Output

```
fruit      red         green
---------- ----------- -----------
Apple      1           0
Orange     1           0
Berry      0           1
PineApple  0           1
```

Comment: I am working using this solution. I am currently trying to transpose the colour column. This will be used on instead of this statement to make it dynamic "in([red],[green])"

Comment: yes, to add more colours, you have to use dynamic sql. Good question, made me stay at work longer today.

Comment: A combination of t-clausen.dk and Maziar Taheri are exactly what i need :). Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Fruits (name varchar(10), color varchar(10))
GO

INSERT #Fruits VALUES ('Apple', 'Red')
INSERT #Fruits VALUES ('Orange', 'Red')
INSERT #Fruits VALUES ('Berry', 'Green')
INSERT #Fruits VALUES ('PineApple', 'Green')
GO

DECLARE @select_query nvarchar(4000);
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR
  FOR SELECT DISTINCT color FROM #Fruits;
DECLARE @color varchar(10);

SET @select_query = N'SELECT name'

OPEN table_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @color;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @select_query = @select_query + N', CASE WHEN color = ''' + @color + N''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ' + @color;
  FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @color;
END
CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;

SET @select_query = @select_query + N' FROM #Fruits';
EXEC sp_executesql @select_query
```

1. Find distinct colors
2. Build SELECT statment
3. Execute it via sp_executesql

Answer (score 2):

try dynamic Pivot. (I Assumed your table's name is t1)

like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = ''

select  @sql = @sql +'['+Colour +'],'
from 
(select distinct colour from t1) t2

set @sql = substring(@sql,1,len(@sql) - 1)


set @sql = '
select * from(
select Fruit, Colour, 1 as CheckMark from t1
) as t2
pivot
(
SUM(CheckMark)
for Colour in ('+@sql+')
) as pivotTable'
execute (@sql)
```

this query returns NULL instead of 0.

hope I helped

Comment: I agree pivot is the way to go for this. + 1. You should include your tables

Comment: I like this answer but due to the sum aggregation it is not what I am looking for

Comment: you can use MIN/MAX instead of SUM though

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Fruit,
   CASE WHEN Colour = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Red
   CASE WHEN Colour = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Green
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```

Comment: The problem is the row content has been hard coded on your example. What is a new colour is introduced? I like the principle but I need this to be dynamic

Comment: @Kip - that's not in the nature of SQL. Each SQL query is always meant to return a result set with the same "shape" - number and types of columns. There are ugly workarounds with dynamic SQL, but I'm not personally a fan.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #t(fruit VARCHAR(10), colour VARCHAR(10))

INSERT #t
SELECT 'Apple',     'Red'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Orange',    'Red'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Berry',     'Green' UNION ALL
SELECT 'PineApple', 'Green'


DECLARE @pivot_columns VARCHAR(2000)
SET @pivot_columns = ''

SELECT @pivot_columns =  @pivot_columns +  '[' + colour + '],'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT colour FROM #t)t

SET @pivot_columns = LEFT(@pivot_columns, LEN(@pivot_columns) - 1)

PRINT @pivot_columns

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = '
    SELECT fruit, ' + @pivot_columns + '
    FROM
    (
        SELECT fruit, colour
        FROM #t
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    COUNT(colour)
    FOR Colour IN (' + @pivot_columns + ')
    ) AS PivotTable'

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)

DROP TABLE #t
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to keep dynamic nature of Maziar Taheri's answer and get rid of nulls:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null
    drop table #t
create table #t (fruit varchar(10), colour varchar(10))
insert #t
select 'Apple',     'Red'   union all
select 'Apple',     'Green'   union all
select 'Apple',     'Yellow'   union all
select 'Apple',     'Yellow'   union all
select 'Orange',    'Red'   union all
select 'Orange',    'Yellow'   union all
select 'Berry',     'Green' union all
select 'Berry',     'Red' union all
select 'Berry',     'Black' union all
select 'PineApple', 'Green'
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @colours nvarchar(max)
select @sql = '', @colours = ''
select  @colours = @colours +'['+Colour +'],',
        @sql = @sql +'isnull(['+Colour+'],0) '+Colour+','
from 
(select distinct colour from #t) t2
set @colours = substring(@colours,1,len(@colours) - 1)
set @sql = substring(@sql,1,len(@sql) - 1)
select @sql = '
select Fruit,'+@sql +' from
(
select Fruit, Colour, 1 as CheckMark from #t
) as t2
pivot
(
SUM(CheckMark)
for Colour in ('+@colours+')
) as pivotTable'
execute (@sql)
```